# How to: Match string from search box and proper case table data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, collation

I have a table that contains company names in this format: `Name Name`, and I have a search box that performs a MySQL query to return data based on the search string.

Let's say my table data looks like this:

```
Company
----------
Name Name
Name Name
```

And so on and so forth, and my query looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
          FROM scoreboard 
         WHERE codcliente = '".$q."' 
            OR nombre LIKE '%".$q."%'";
```

Now, everything works fine when I try: `nam`, `Nam`, `Name`, `Name N`, `NAM`, `NAME`, and `NAME N`. My question is why doesn't it work with: `name` or `name n`? Obviously it might have to do with the mixed case in the table data, but if so, why does `nam` work?

Here's the `SHOW CREATE TABLE scoreboard` result:

```
CREATE TABLE `scoreboard` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `codcliente` text,
  `nombre` text,
  `ejecutivo` text,
  `banca_as400` text,
  `banca_real` text,
  `ingresos` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ciiu` text,
  `division` text,
  `actividad` text,
  `riesgo_industria` text,
  `riesgo_cliente` text,
  `fecha` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `analista` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Please update to include the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the `scoreboard` table.  I want to see the collation, particularly...

Comment: Updated to include the create table code @omg.

Comment: @rdrgrtz :) Actually he asked you to run `SHOW CREATE TABLE scoreboard` in MySQL and add the output here.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure how to do it. Could you post the complete query? I'm getting an error about default schema in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: @karolis Nevermind, got it working. Posted result in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid case problems, compare them all in uppercase so you won't be disturbed by case.

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
          FROM scoreboard 
         WHERE upper(codcliente) = '".strtoupper($q)."' 
            OR upper(nombre) LIKE '%".strtoupper($q)."%'";
```

Seems hacky, but nevertheless reliable.

Comment: What if the user types in lowercase? Not affected? (I'm gonna try it out in a bit). @caffein

Comment: The aboce code, transforms everuy user input as well as the database info into uppercase. It only does so in the WHERE/OR clause, so your input and display won't be affected.

Comment: Thanks @caffein! I modified it a bit, to: `$sql="SELECT * FROM scoreboard WHERE codcliente = '".$q."' OR lower(nombre) LIKE '%".strtolower($q)."%'";` since `codcliente` is a numeric value and doesn't need case, and I like working with lower case :)

Comment: @rdrgrtz lower, upper, it's up to you. But the create table you showed in the question stated  `nombre text,` so I assumed it was... text.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that @caffein, it's just that I'm migrating from an Excel sheet and I've had a lot of problems in the past with leading zeroes, so that's why I made the `codcliente` (which is basically the customer number) text.